# How do I implement this direct messaging feature in a Twitter style app using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I'm trying to implement a direct messaging feature that is quite similar to Twitter using Rails, and I was wondering what I am doing wrong here.  I am trying to restrict direct messaging to both followers and users that a user is following, but I can only restrict the direct messaging to followers, but for some reason can't add this feature for the users a user is following.

This is the relevant code in: `app/controllers/messages_controller.rb`

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user
  before_action :find_user_id, only: :create

def create
    @message = current_user.messages.build(message_params)
    @message.recipient_id = @recipient.id
    if @message.save
      flash[:success] = "You successfully sent a message to #{@message.recipient.username}!"
      redirect_to messages_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error sending your message, try again!"
      redirect_to messages_path
    end
  end

 private

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:recipient_id, :content)
  end

  def find_user_id
    username = params[:message][:recipient].downcase
    @recipient = User.where('lower(username) = ?', username).first
    if @recipient.nil?
      flash[:error] = "Invalid username"
      redirect_to messages_path
    elsif @recipient.following?(current_user) == nil || @recipient.follower?(current_user) == nil
      flash[:error] =
          "You can only direct message followers or users you are following"
      redirect_to messages_path
    end
  end
end
```

The problem area specifically seems to be this line of code here:

```
elsif @recipient.following?(current_user) == nil || @recipient.follower?(current_user) == nil

elsif @recipient.following?(current_user) == nil works properly, but the latter code doesn't.  The code from those two lines are from: app/models/user.rb

  def follower?(other_user)
    relationships.find_by(follower_id: other_user.id)
  end

  def following?(other_user)
    relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end
```

If anybody can help me out or suggest some possible fixes to this problem it'd be greatly appreciated.  If you need more information to understand the code or to fix the problem, please don't hesitate to ask!

Here's some additional information for understanding the data model behind this:

In the db/migrate folder:

```
class CreateRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :relationships do |t|
      t.integer :follower_id
      t.integer :followed_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :relationships, :follower_id
    add_index :relationships, :followed_id
    add_index :relationships, [:follower_id, :followed_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

Also in the same directory:

```
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.integer :sender_id
      t.integer :recipient_id
      t.string  :content

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :messages, [:sender_id, :recipient_id, :content]
  end
end
```

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you declaring follower and following attributes?

Comment: I added some additional code to help you better understand the question

Comment: I mean, where are `def follower?(other_user)`, etc.

Comment: def follower?(other_user) is just this function here: def follower?(other_user)
    relationships.find_by(follower_id: other_user.id)
  end